# Silverlight 3.0 and MVVM Pattern

Tags: silverlight-3.0

i am working on this  article here  they are using Silverlight 4. 
[link text](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/EConsultancy/715/)

but i am using Silverlight 3.but  for button  we are  not able  to  find the  command

**Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.GetPerson, ElementName= LayoutRoot }"**

```
<Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,112,0,0" Name="button1"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"  Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.GetPerson, ElementName= LayoutRoot }" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Age, ElementName=hi}"  />
```

so in Silverlight 3  what  should i  do  to get this  Command property for the button

any help  would be great

Answer (score 0):

A command is a bindable way of associating an action to a control (button for instance).
The command controls 2 things:

- whether it can be executed
- what to do when it's executed

by implementing the [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(VS.95).aspx) interface

They've been around for a while in WPF and were recently added to SL4

If you want your code to work in SL3 you'll have to bind the IsEnabled property to a property in your view model that has the same logic as the CanExecute implementation of the command
and to add a Click event handler for the button which has the same logic has the command's Execute

Also, this button passes a parameter to the command (CommandParameter), you'll have to handle passing this parameter manually

Answer (score 0):

You could use a framework like [prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/), add the relevant dll's to your project, then add a reference to the top of page like so

```
xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation"
```

Then declare the prison attribute on your button

```
<Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,112,0,0" Name="button1"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"  Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.GetPerson, ElementName= LayoutRoot }" 
        prism:Click.Command={Binding SomeCommand}
        prism:Click.CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Age, ElementName=hi}"  />
```